# Branch.io not giving preview for Facebook, working on linkedIn and Twitter

Tags: swift, sharing, branch.io

I am using branch.io for sharing. When I am sharing Facebook not giving a preview. Same is working on Linkedin and Twitter

**let buo1 = BranchUniversalObject.init(canonicalIdentifier: "https://appName.app.link/(videoId)")

```
    buo1.title = "#I am a magnet - watch this magnet video on appName."
    //buo.contentDescription = "My Content Description"
    buo1.imageUrl = imageUrl
    buo1.publiclyIndex = true
    buo1.locallyIndex = true
    buo1.contentMetadata.customMetadata["key1"] = "value1"

    let lp: BranchLinkProperties = BranchLinkProperties()
    lp.channel = "whatsapp"
    lp.channel = "Twitter"
    lp.channel = "LinkedIn"
    lp.channel = "instagram"
    lp.channel = "Mail"
    lp.channel = "Facebook"
    lp.feature = "sharing"
    lp.campaign = "content 123 launch"
    lp.stage = "new user"
    lp.tags = ["four", "five", "six"]

    lp.addControlParam("$desktop_url", withValue: "https://appName.app.link/desktop")
    lp.addControlParam("$ios_url", withValue: "https://appName.app.link/ios")
    lp.addControlParam("$ipad_url", withValue: "https://appName.app.link/ios")
    lp.addControlParam("$android_url", withValue: "https://appName.app.link/android")
    lp.addControlParam("$match_duration", withValue: "2000")**
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook scrapes the link as per the OG tags. In your BUO object please add the necessary OG tags property so that the image can be rendered properly.

Here is the documentation link which you can refer to for custom OG tags - https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/creating-a-deep-link#section-open-graph

Comment: if possible can you provide the source code for this?